# How can "proposed new times" be retrieved for an event?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apis-explorer

**TL;DR:** When an attendee has proposed a new time for an event, is it possible for the organizer to retrieve the proposed new time via the Google Calendar API, e.g. from [*Events: get*](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) or [*Events: list*](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list)?

### Example flow

1. Organizer invites Attendee to an event at 1700 EDT

   [image: Organizer's event at 1700 EDT]
2. Attendee receives the event invitation for 1500 MDT

   [image: Attendee's event at 1500 MDT]
3. Attendee proposes a new time of 1530 MDT

   [image: Attendee clicks on "Propose a new time"]

   [image: Attendee chooses 1530 MDT]

   [image: Attendee sees that the new time is pending approval]
4. Organizer sees that there is a proposed new time

   [image: Organizer sees that there is a proposed new time to approve]

### Resulting event data from the Google Calendar API

When the organizer retrieves the above event via the [*Events: get*](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) and [*Events: list*](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) APIs, all they see is that the attendee has a *tentative* response status.  There is nothing to indicate that a new time has been proposed, nor what that time is:

```
{
  ...,
  "kind": "calendar#event",
  "organizer": {
    "email": "organizer@example.com",
    "self": true
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2019-09-17T17:00:00-04:00"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2019-09-17T17:30:00-04:00"
  },
  "attendees": [
    {
      "email": "attendee@example.com",
      "responseStatus": "tentative"
    },
    {
      "email": "organizer@example.com",
      "organizer": true,
      "self": true,
      "responseStatus": "accepted"
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Comment: any update on this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Google Calendar team has confirmed that, as of September 2019, this is not available via the API and there is no ongoing work to add it to the API.

Comment: BOOOOOO! Thank you for following up though
1

Comment: Not that I know of, sadly.

Comment: very sad :( This feature would really come in handy for me

Comment: As of now the feature is still a request only. Please vote here so it gets voted up. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170465098?pli=1