# Automatically accept "New Time Proposal" on Google Calendar without webhook?

Tags: ruby, google-calendar-api

OK, so I'm creating events and sending invites through my google service account and api.  I'm obviously the organizer of these events.  I don't actually man this calendar daily.  I'd like to automatically accept someone's "new time proposal".  Is there a way to do that WITHOUT setting up webhooks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Unfortunately it is not possible to retrieve via API an new time proposal from the invitees

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57926960/how-can-proposed-new-times-be-retrieved-for-an-event).